How can we split a terraform module into multiple modules
I'm new to terraform so pardon my inexperience. I have a terraform file to create multiple big query table. we specify table config in tables array. Since this is a consolidated repository the number of table in array is exceeding 200. I need to divide this module into sub modules where the parent module calls the sub module. I am adding sample code below the number of objects in tables = [] is more than 200.
codes
module "bq_module_tables" {
  source = "tfregistry..XXX.com/XXX/bigquery/gcp"
  depends_on          = [module.bq_module_dset]
  project_id          = var.gcp_project_id
  deletion_protection = false #var.deletion_protection
  tables = [
    {
      table_id            = var.tbl_id
      dataset_id          = var.dataset_id
      schema              = "${path.module}/schemas/ssrin113.json"
      clustering          = []
      expiration_time     = null
      deletion_protection = false #var.deletion_protection
      range_partitioning  = null
      time_partitioning = {
        type                     = "DAY",
        field                    = null,
        require_partition_filter = false,
        expiration_ms            = null,
      },
      labels = {
        env      = var.app_environment
        billable = "false"
      }
    },
    {
      table_id            = var.tbl_id_1
      dataset_id          = var.dataset_id_1
      schema              = "${path.module}/schemas/na_formatted_messages.json"
      clustering          = []
      expiration_time     = null
      deletion_protection = false #var.deletion_protection
      range_partitioning  = null
      time_partitioning = {
        type                     = "DAY",
        field                    = null,
        require_partition_filter = false,
        expiration_ms            = null,
      },
      labels = {
        env      = var.app_environment
        billable = "false"
      }
    }
  ]
}```


Unfortunately there isn't enough information in your question to give a precise answer -- you haven't shown anything from the module that you would be modifying -- but as a starting point you could read Refactoring in the Terraform documentation, and in particular Splitting one Module into Multiple.

That documentation describes how you can use moved blocks to explain to Terraform how the modules evolved over time, so Terraform can automatically update its records (in the state) to match. Of course, you'll also need to actually make the changes to the configuration before you add the moved blocks to explain them, so I expect you'll probably have more questions before reaching that point. You could update your question to ask something more specific once you have a strong idea of what your goal is.

I found the solution. The terraform consider all the .tf files as a single file when processing so we can create new tf files in same folder with different module name to divide a single module into multiple files. The down side is the tables will be destroyed and recreated. One way to avoid that is by using "terraform state mv" command and change meta data from old module to new module.
